# Map Printers based on physical location

Tags: printing, group-policy, network-printer

I work at a company where we have 2 locations which are close fairly to each other, and some users often travel between buildings with laptops. We're just setting up our AD environment, and I'm looking for a way to map the printers at each building only if you're in that building.

I read somewhere about doing it using Group Policy Preferences, and Item Level Targeting using IP address, but then the printers only get added or removed when a `gpupdate` is performed. So if someone brings their laptop into the other building, and the PC is on the whole time, they won't have the proper printer unless they reboot.

Is there a way for me to map printers based on where the computer is physically (like something that would map the printers immediately when it connects to a network, based on the newly connected IP?) We do have separate IP blocks at the 2 buildings, so a solution that uses IP is definitely an option. If not, I'm likely going to just map the printers for both buildings and let the user decide which printer to print to.

EDIT: some more information:

One of the locations has multiple printers
Most of those printers are the same model (those that aren't will likely be mapped using a security group or other method, because they're special use printers like label printers.)

Comment: Are the printers identical (or at least very similar) in their function and drivers? (Imagine someone physically swapped the printers between two sites, would the PCs just continue printing with no reconfiguration?)

Comment: They are the same exact model. So same driver and everything

Answer (score 0):

There are some options which don't involve AD:

> They are the same exact model. So same driver and everything

You could use DNS trickery to assign the same domain name to both printers. This depends on your LAN DNS server's capabilities – it has to *somehow* return different answers when queried from different sites. (For example BIND9 could probably achieve this through "views".) Note that this only works as long as the laptops *use* your internal DNS server and aren't permanently set to use 8.8.8.8 or something.

Depending on the network layout, you could use either IP anycast or DNAT to assign the same IP address to both printers, which will trick computers into always connecting to the "nearest" device.

DNAT should always work, but requires the printers to be in a separate subnet from the laptops (due to the usual "NAT loopback" story). Choose a private IP address from a dedicated subnet – i.e. belonging neither to site A, nor to site B. In each router, add a firewall rule such as `ip daddr <shared_IP> dnat to <printer_IP>` that'll point to the nearest device. (I'm using *nft* syntax in this example.) Then configure all clients to print through that shared IP address.

Anycast isn't guaranteed to work (printers aren't exactly servers), but it might work as long as the printer supports having two IP addresses at once: the first one unique (exactly as usual), the second one identical across all printers (and belonging to a subnet that's neither site A nor site B). Then each of your LAN routers needs a route like `dst <shared_IP> via <unique_IP>`, routing the packets to the most appropriate device.

Comment: While this sounds like it might be a possible solution, I don't think it's ideal in my case. One building has multiple printers, so I'd like to be able to easily remove all printers from one location and add all for the other. However, if no other solutions come to light, I'll keep this in mind as an option